# Google Login gives "This browser or app may not be secure"

Tags: google-sites, google-api-js-client

I am testing my local app on https://localhost:44367/ using Chrome for google login.

My app is Angular 6 using .Net core

When i try to login using my credentials, it gives Error saying

Couldn't sign you in
This browser or app may not be secure.
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

This used to work locally but it stopped working as of today.

Please help me

thanks

Comment: Are you using a certificate for your local site? This may be what the google auth servers are having an issue with. Try installing a self-signed certificate on your local server. I am going to assume you're using a IIS server since you're using .NET core so try the instructions listed here https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/132438. Once you have generated your certificate, install it on your server.

Comment: I don't know if that is it. So the problem is, if i use the browser that opens up when you start the IIS on visual studio, it gives that error but if i open a new Chrome browser and use the LocalHost:xxxxxx it works. So i am a little confused and i just found this out that it works on a separate browser.

Comment: Got the same isse. Works fine on IE

Comment: there is probably issues with cookies. i used a different browser and it worked. so I cleared the cookies (the app domain only) on my main browser and got it to work. it might be different for you but it worked on mine

Answer (score 2):

**I've tried a lot of methods but only one worked for me.** I was working with react.js and electron.js with firebase authentication then i get the same problem. This is what i did to solve my problem.

```
electron.app.on("ready", ()=>{
  session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders((details, callback)=>{
  details.requestHeaders["User-Agent"] = "Chrome",
  callback({cancel: false, requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders})
 })
  createWindow()
})
```

**Alternatively You can also try this** pass the userAgent value to Chrome when loading the URL as follows.

```
window.loadURL('/path/to/your/index.html`,  {userAgent: "Chrome"})
```

**Good Luck ✔✔✨✨**

Answer (score 0):

Please try sending another `User Agent` header from your app when you make requests to Google. They recently banned many "less secure apps".